# u don't wind up crowd at 4-0

Tags: meaning

*According to Sky Italia, Mou said it's just his opinion, but "**u don't wind up crowd at 4-0. You do it at 1-0. It's humiliating**.*"

Can you please tell me what the meaning of the part in quotation marks is. The words were reportedly told by Jose Mourinho to Andrea Conte after his Manchester United was defeated by Chelsea in the today match in Premier League.

Comment: In idiomatic (and grammatical) English, it should be *You don't wind up **the crowd***, which indeed is the version reported on many Internet sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like *wind up* means *pump up, excite, fire up, etc*.

> [wind someone up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wind+up)
>   *Inf. Fig.* to get someone excited.

We can rewrite it to be something like

> You don't pump up the crowd when the score is 4-0. You do it at 1-0. It's humiliating.

So it sounds like the "you" (whoever "you" is) didn't start pumping up the crowd until the score was 4-0. I assume by that point, it was too late for the losing team to recover. Mourinho believes "you" should have started winding up the crowd much sooner, when the score was 1-0. "It's humiliating" likely refers to the fact that no effort was made to wind up the crowd sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the speaker is saying that you should get the crowd wound up (excited) after the first goal and not wait until the fourth. Having the crowd not cheer until the fourth goal would be humiliating.